# XSLT - insert a new element into a multi elements (list)

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml as shown below:

```
<input>
    <name>inputName</name>
    <type>drop</type>
    <inputListItem>
        <name>item1</name>
        <value>value1</value>
    </inputListItem>
    <inputListItem>
        <name>item2</name>
        <value>value2</value>
    </inputListItem>
    <inputListItem>
       ...
    </inputListItem>
    <inputListItem>
      ...
    </inputListItem>
    ...
</input>
```

What I need is to add an element "listValues" before the first "inputListItem" as:

```
<input>
    <name>inputName</name>
    <type>drop</type>
    <listValues>
      <inputListItem>
        <name>item1</name>
        <value>value1</value>
      </inputListItem>
      <inputListItem>
        <name>item2</name>
        <value>value2</value>
      </inputListItem>
      <inputListItem>
         ...
      </inputListItem>
      <inputListItem>
        ...
      </inputListItem>
      ...
    </listValues>
</input>
```

I tried for some hours but my xslt still does not work. Can someone please help.

Many thanks

Comment: Post u r tried XSLT.

Comment: share the xslt which you have used.

Comment: "*What I need is to add an element "listValues" before the first "inputListItem"*" Actually, your example shows that you want to add the  `listValues` element as the **parent** of all `inputListItem` elements.

Comment: thanks.michael, listValues element needs to be added as the parent of all inputListItem elements.